# Round button java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, rounding

I made a simple game, everything works as I imagined. only would like to instead default jbutons have a circular button. Is there a built-in Java function for changing the shape buttons?![game`   mreza=new JButton[8][8];

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
        mreza[i][j]=new JButton();
        //mreza[i][j].setBorder( BorderFactory.createBevelBorder ( BevelBorder.RAISED, Color.blue, Color.red ) );


p.add(mreza[i][j]);
Akcija ak=new Akcija();
mreza[i][j].addActionListener(ak);`][1]
```

Comment: No, there's no built-in functionality for this, but there are ways of getting around this that a little searching will bring to you.

Comment: Please have a look at [this link](http://java-swing-tips.blogspot.com/2008/07/create-round-image-jbutton.html) for instance.

Comment: Thanks ! I will look. I was hoping that java have some implemetn metod to change  basic shapes of buttons :)

Comment: It would be nice if they did, but Swing is somewhat limited in this regard.

Comment: *"I was hoping that java have some implemetn metod to change basic shapes of buttons"*  Whereas I'm glad it doesn't.  Round buttons are less usable that square/rectangular ones, especially when it comes to clicking on them using a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this subclass of JButton](https://github.com/lukakralj/Useful_misc/blob/master/Java/ovalButton/OvalButton.java).
It behaves like a normal button so you won't need to change any code apart from the line where you instantiate it:

```
mreza[i][j]=new OvalButton();
```

(It is only called oval because if you stretch it the button will become an oval, however if you set it's width and height to be the same then it's a circle.)
The button will only respond if clicked within the borders of the circle.